# Fourier transformation of a Heaviside function 5

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

So I have function $$f(t) = 5+H(t-2)$$

and from that I can gather that $$f(t) = 6,  t[2,\infty]$$
$$f(t) = 0, t[-\infty,2[$$

So I calculated $$\int_{2}^\infty6e^{-i\omega t}$$

and this one does get a "sensible answer", but is much different from what I get when I use Wolfram Alpha's Fourier Transformation widget to check the answer. 
My answer is $\frac{-6ie^{-2i\omega}}{\omega}$, but Wolfram Alpha spits out answer with delta functions and other scrap.

[Wolfram widget](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%225%2BH(t-2)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22Fourier+transform%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D)

Comment: What is your "sensible answer?"

Comment: Do you know what the Fourier transform of a step function is? If so, then use time shifting properties.

Comment: My answer was what you'd get from integrating from 2 to inf of $6e^{-i\omega t}$, [like so](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=from+2+to+inf+integral+of+6e%5E(-iwt)+dt)

Comment: @Grak Your analysis is not correct unless $\omega$ has a negative imaginary part.

Comment: I noticed what I was thinking wrong with the function, but how could I work out the heaviside function turn into something more sensible. I'm thinking that I will either want to move the function on time-level so that it jumps at y-axis (why?) or that it will be at 0 on x-axis when heaviside equals 0 (how?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't give sense to the Fourier transform of $f(t) = 5 + H(t-2)$ unless you interpret it in the sense of [(Schwartz) distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform).

It might be useful for an engineer to write, for example,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 5\cdot e^{-i t \omega } \,dt = 10 \pi \delta \tag{1}
$$
but since the integral on the left-hand side of $(1)$ does not converge, this has no mathematical sense. However if we see the constant function $t\mapsto5$ as an element of the space $\mathcal{S}'(\Bbb{R})$ of  [tempered distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform), then it is true that
$$
\mathcal{F}\{5\}(\omega) = 10\pi\delta \tag{2}
$$
Here $(2)$ has a precise meaning, but one must know some distribution theory in order to understand it.

Now, one learns that

$
\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\phantom{-}\displaystyle\mathcal{F}\{H\}(\omega) = \pi \delta -i$ [$\displaystyle\operatorname{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Distribution_theory)

We can now find the Fourier transform of $f$ by making use (as hinted in the comments) of the following time shifting property.

> **Proposition:** Let $u\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ and $a\in\Bbb{R}$. Then
>   $$
> \mathcal{F}\{\tau_a u\}(\omega) = e^{-i a \omega}\mathcal{F}\{u\}(\omega)
> $$
>   Here $\tau_au := u \circ f$ where $f(t) := t-a$.

We obtain
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\{5+H(t-2)\} &= \mathcal{F}\{5\} + \mathcal{F}\{H(t-2)\}\\
&=10\pi\delta+\pi e^{-2i\omega}\delta-i e^{-2i\omega} \operatorname{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right) \\
&=10\pi\delta+\pi\delta-i e^{-2i\omega} \operatorname{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right)
\end{align}

**Note.** Be careful interpreting results from Wolfram Alpha (which are wrong sometimes!).

The [Fourier transform documentation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html) says (just after equation $(16)$) that Wolfram Alpha adopted the convention
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f\} := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{i\omega t} \,dt
$$

The answer obtained here is for
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f\} := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i\omega t} \,dt
$$

The "scrap" that Wolfram Alpha "spits out" is correct if you interpret the $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\omega}$ in $\displaystyle\frac{i e^{2 i \omega}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\omega}$ as the distribution $\displaystyle\operatorname{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right)$.